# User for creating test tables in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, docker

I am sorry for a newbie question. I installed Oracle Database 18 from [official dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.3.0/Dockerfile). Dockerfile installs Oracle Database and creates the following users: SYS, SYSTEM AND PDBADMIN.

1) What user should I use to create a test table? Should I create a separate user or grant 'create table' permission to PDBADMIN, for example? What is the common practice?

2) What schema_name should I specify?

First I need to create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);
```

Now if I try to create this table with PDBADMIN I get the following error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

**EDIT1**: I run the container as follows:

```
sudo docker build -t oracle/database-se:18.3.0 --build-arg DB_EDITION=SE2 .
sudo docker run -d -it --rm --name oracle18se oracle/database-se:18.3.0
```

for more information see the the [instruction I followed](https://developernote.com/2019/03/running-oracle-database-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

**EDIT2:** Looks like my database (PDB) name is ORCLPDB1, because I did not specify neither ORACLE_SID nor ORACLE_PDB when I run the container.

Comment: Are you following the documentation? https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance#running-oracle-database-in-a-docker-container It contains a series of environment variables parameters to set database name, password, etc.

Comment: @DaniloCabello no, I followed some instruction I found in the internet, see EDIT1, but I can rebuild and restart the container.

Comment: You might also want to use an Oracle CREATE TABLE statement. INT and VARCHAR are not Oracle datatypes. You want NUMBER and VARCHAR2.

Comment: @DaniloCabello Now I have two ORACLE_SIDs: ORCLCDB and ORCLPDB1 that I specify in the container with 'export ORACLE_SID=...", but ORACLE_PDB is empty and it is not clear what is my database name.